# Access Report / SQL DCount function

Tags: database, ms-access

I have the following Tables and Fields in my DB:

```
tblProductionRecords:
pk_fldProductionRecordID,
fk_fldJobNumber_ID,
fldPartsCompleted,

tblJobs:
pk_fldJobID,
fldJobNumber

tblEmployee_ProductionRecord:
pk_fldEmp_ProdRec,
fk_fldProdRec_ID,
fk_fldEmployee_ID,
fldHours

tblEmployees:
pk_fldEmployeeID,
FldName
```

So what I am tracking is production records for a given job.  The pieces of the production records are:
Part Quantities.
Which employee(s) were in involved with completing the quantities (it could be 1 or more employees, hence the Many to Many relationship between employees and production records)
And how many hours each employee spent completing the quantities.

The problem I am faced with is tracking my total quantities for a job on my report.  When a given production record has ore that one employee that worked on those quantities, the quantities are added for each employee record.  So lets same 3 employees work on a job and the 3 of them created completed 1000 parts.  In my report, it will show a total of 3000 completed.

I understand creating groups, footer, headers, running sums and the Count function (I believe).

What I suspect I need is a field in my Query that is a sum of how many records are in tblEmployee_ProductionRecord where fldProdRec_ID = "the current production record" in the detailed section.  With that number I can divide the total completed quantities between the 3 (or how ever many) employees and do a sum of that field.

I hope this is clear enough.  I and sincerly appriciate any help!

David

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, your example (3 employees work on a job and each one created 1000 parts) will look like this in the tables:

**tblEmployee_ProductionRecord:**

```
pk_fldEmp_ProdRec   fk_fldProdRec_ID    fk_fldEmployee_ID   fldHours
1                   1                   1                   5
2                   2                   2                   5
3                   3                   3                   5
```

**tblProductionRecords:**

```
pk_fldProductionRecordID    fk_fldJobNumber_ID  fldPartsCompleted
1                           1                   1000
2                           1                   1000
3                           1                   1000
```

If yes, try the following query:

```
SELECT
    tblProductionRecords.fk_fldJobNumber_ID, 
    Count(tblEmployee_ProductionRecord.pk_fldEmp_ProdRec) AS EmployeeCount,
    Sum(tblProductionRecords.fldPartsCompleted) AS CompletedSum
FROM 
    tblEmployee_ProductionRecord 
    INNER JOIN tblProductionRecords ON tblEmployee_ProductionRecord.fk_fldProdRec_ID 
                = tblProductionRecords.pk_fldProductionRecordID
GROUP BY 
    tblProductionRecords.fk_fldJobNumber_ID
HAVING
    tblProductionRecords.fk_fldJobNumber_ID=1;
```

This will return the following result:

```
fk_fldJobNumber_ID  EmployeeCount   CompletedSum
1                   3               3000
```

--> for Job number one, three employees created a total of 3000 parts.

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Hello Christian - thank you for your response.  It is not that the 3 employees created 1000 parts each, but 3 employees created 1000 total between the 3 of them.  So there is one record in tblProductionRecords with a PartsCompleted of 3000 and 3 records in tblEmployee_ProductionRecord pointing to the one production record of 3000 parts completed.

Comment: @user902949: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. If 3 employees created 1000 parts total (say, 300+300+400), then the record in tblProductionRecords will have PartsCompleted = 3000? I would have expected it to be 1000 (the total number of parts the employees created). Can you clarify this (or even better, edit your question and provide some sample data for the tables)?